# Algorithm to evenly distribute a hierarchical dataset

Tags: algorithms

I am working on a chatbot designer interface. The dataset for the conversation flow consists of messages. Each message has a parent message and can have multiple possible next messages. The system displays one of the possible next messages depending on the reply. This makes it a complicated structure of parent-children relations.

On the dialog flow designer interface, the user is able to drag messages around in order to achieve a visual clarity of the designer dialog flow. This is loads of work for the user.

I want to implement an algo that would do this job for the user. So the messages should distribute themselves at even distances and making sure that their children are also around their parent message evenly distributed.

I have not studied algos, so I am not sure what jargon to look for. I don't even know the proper tag to use in this question. What this kind of algorithm is called and how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for something like:  Force Directed Layout/network Algorithms

Comment: I don't understand what "depending on the reply" means.

Comment: @D.W. it means since there are multiple possible children (next messages); the system displays next message depending on what the user has replied to the current message.

Comment: We generally encourage you to [edit] your question rather than leaving clarifications in the comments, so people can understand what you're asking without having to read the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an algorithm for [graph layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing).  There are many out there, as well as some tools.